# Delete is creating deadlock in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, database-deadlocks

I have two tables say T1 and T2. T1 has a reference in T2 as seen below:

Table: T1

```
|Col1|
|v1  |
|v2  |
|v3  |
```

Table: T2

```
|Id|Col1|Col2|
|1 |v1  |v2  |
|2 |v2  |v1  |
|3 |v1  |v3  |
|4 |v3  |v1  |
```

So we have a primary key of T1 as foreign keys of T2 Col1 and Col2 both.
Now whenever a request for delete comes for T1 (say I want to delete v1), its referenced row needs to be deleted first from T2(in this case Id 1,2,3,4 in T2 ) and then the record in T1 will delete.

Now when we are trying to delete this using Entity framework it got stuck in deadlock and fails.

Any suggestion on how to resolve this?

Updated EF code:

```
 using (_dbContext as IDisposable)
                {

                        var t1= _dbContext.T1
                        .Include(t1 => t1.Table3)
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Col1);

                         var lstT2 = _dbContext.T2
                        .Where(x => x.Col1 == value ||
                                    x.Col2== value).ToList();

                    using (var transaction = _dbContext.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            foreach (var t2 in lstT2)
                            {
                                _dbContext.T2.Remove(t2);
                                _dbContext.SaveChanges();
                            }
                            _dbContext.T1.Remove(t1);

                            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
                            transaction.Commit();

                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                            NLogger.Log(LogLevel.Error, ex.Message);
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Why would that result in a deadlock? How did you determine that? What does your code look like, and what SQL does it generate?

Comment: You haven't provided the code or the table schemas so one can only guess. Delete doesn't cause deadlocks. Missing indexes though, do. Badly written,long running transactions. Using excessive locking while reading. For example, if the keys aren't indexed the server will have to scan the entire table to find matching rows, thus locking far more rows than required

Comment: Deadlocks are caused when queries lock too much and try to perform operations in conficting sequence. A plain-old `SaveChanges` *shouldn't* lock as it only performs a `DELETE`. If you used a big transaction to cover both *reading* entities and *deleting* them, you acquired shared locks on them for the duration of the transaction for no reason. If you use a transaction per request in an ASP.NET application you also take excessive transactions for no reason. That's a well known *anti*pattern

Comment: The proper, scalable way to handle conflicts is to *NOT* use transactions but optimistic locking. This isn't new or specific to EF or SQL Server, it applies to every system with more than a couple of users, whether it's a client/server, desktop, web or service application. It's also explained in all EF docs and tutorials. Instead of using a transaction to ensure the data you read hasn't changed until you delete it, ADO.NET/EF/NH whatever uses a DB-provided rowversion column to detect whether someone else modified that row since it was last read. This can lead to 10x better perf - for starters

Comment: @CodeCaster: I found it using SQL Profiler. It generates SQL for deleting the T2 Columns followed by T1 column.

Comment: The problem occurss when I try to send delete for multiple T1 rows at a time, this results into many more T2 rows to be deleted first and then the respective T1 row.